# Type error when asigning tuple in do notation in haskell

Tags: haskell

This is the haskell code I have:

```
myFold:: ([a] -> (b, [a])) -> [a] -> [b]
myFold fn []  = []
myFold fn lst = do
    (ast, newLst) <- (fn lst)
    myFold fn newLst ++ [ast]
```

I think everybody who knows haskell will get what I want to do. However this code is wrong and I really don't get why. The compiler complains that the types don't match in the line `(ast, newLst) <- (fn lst)` and I cannot see what's wrong.. Can somebody point me to how the syntax must be? Also I am pretty sure that there are better ways to do this so please feel free to provide alternatives.

Comment: Did you mean to use `let` instead of `<-`?

Comment: There is no assignment in Haskell. `<-` isn't an assignment, and `do` and `return` don't do what similarly named constructs do in other languages. You need a better Haskell tutorial.

Comment: maybe, I will try it out and see if the result matches my expectation

Comment: sry, the `return` was a copy & paste error from another function... I think let does the trick

Comment: `<-` is used to "extract" values from a monadish value. In your case (a list function) it could be used to iterate over the elements of a list.

Comment: Yup, `let` does the trick. @melpomene want to create a real answer or should I just delete the question for my confusion about the syntax?

Comment: When starting out, I recommend using `>>=` et al. explicitly, rather than using `do` notation. Use `do` once you understand what benefits it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Stop using `do` notation. It does not do what you think it does.**

Long answer:

`do`-notation is being misused here. I won't do a full monad tutorial here, but I'll show you what you should have done, line by line.

Firstly, the line `myFold fn lst = do` is wrong, because you shouldn't be using `do`-notation, so let's remove it:

```
myFold fn lst =
```

Secondly, the line `(ast, newLst) <- (fn lst)` is misusing a construct in `do`-notation, namely the arrow. What you *actually* want is a plain old `let`-statement, so let's replace that, noting that we also need an accompanying `in` later.

```
    let (ast, newLst) = fn lst
```

Thirdly, you need an `in` when you express the value you want to return:

```
    in myFold fn newLst ++ [ast]
```

So, all in all:

```
myFold fn lst =
    let (ast, newLst) = fn lst
    in myFold fn newLst ++ [ast]
```

If you want to find out how to *properly* use `do`-notation, provided that you understand Monads, there are [plenty](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) [of tutorials](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) available online. I will not explain this here because this is completely outside the scope of the core issue in this code.

Comment: I think you meant to write: **Stop using `do` notation. It does not `do` what you think it does.** ;-)